# Why is there a memory leak when an exception is thrown from a constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, memory-leaks

I read the book *C++ How to Program 8th Edition* by *Paul Deitel*. There is a statement at p.645:

> When an exception is thrown from the constructor for an object that's created in a new expression, the dynamically allocated memory for that object is released.

To verify this statement, I wrote code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <memory>

class A{
public:
  A(){std::cout << "A is coming." << std::endl;}
  ~A(){std::cout << "A is leaving." << std::endl;}
};
class B
{
public:
  B()
  {
    std::cout << "B is coming." << std::endl;
    A b;
    throw 3;
  }
  ~B(){std::cout << "B is leaving." << std::endl;}
};

int main(void)
{
    try
    {
        std::shared_ptr<B> pi(new B);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
      std::cout << "Exception handled!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
B is coming.
A is coming.
A is leaving.
Exception handled!
```

This shows that B's destructor isn't invoked, which seems to conflict with the statement above.

Is my code correct to verify the statement? If not, how should I modify it? If yes, does it mean that the statement is wrong?

Comment: Just because the destructor wasn't called doesn't mean its memory is leaked. I don't see any memory leak in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that everything in the ctor of `B` up to the point of the exception is destruction. An instance of `B` itself was never constructed, therefore it must not be destructed. Note also that `pi` was never constructed.

```
std::shared_ptr<B> pi(new B)  - start with new B
new B                         - triggers the ctor of B
std::cout ...                 - the output 
A b;                          - construct an A
throw 3;                      - calls ~A()
                              - rewind, new B is "aborted"
                              - std::shared_ptr<B> pi(new B) is "aborted"
```

You could modify your code to see, that the constructor of the `std::shared_ptr` is never hit by replacing it with a new class of yours, taking a pointer:

```
struct T {
  T(B*) { std::cout << "T::T()\n"; }
};
...
try
{
    T pi(new B);  // instead of std::shared_ptr<B> pi(new B);
}
...
```

The constructor of `T` will not be hit (cf. "`pi` was never constructed").

Now assume that the constructor of `B` would allocate memory as in:

```
B()
{
  A* a = new A();   // in contrast to A a;
  throw 3;
}
```

were previously `A::~A()` was called, that is a was deconstructed, we now have a pointer, and pointers don't need to be deconstructed. However the memory allocated and assigned to a is **not** deleted. (Had you used a smart pointer `std::unique_ptr<A> a = std::make_unique<A>();`, the memory would have been released, because the destructor of `std::unique_ptr<A>` is called and it will release the memory.)

Comment: And this is one reason why smart pointers can be important - if B's constructor had done a raw memory allocation into a plain-old-pointer before the exception, there wouldn't be an automatic release of *that* memory.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Sorry, I'm still kinda unsure about ur answer. how can we know that new B is "aborted, in other words, pi was never constructed"? Can you explain in theory or provide proving code?

Comment: @Neymar87 When calling any function, including constructors, all expressions that make up the arguments are fully evaluated before calling the function. So since `new B` is an argument to the call to construct `pi` and `new B` never completes due to throwing an exception, `pi`'s constructor is never entered.

Comment: Can you suggest using a unique ptr instead of a shared one inside the ctor of `B` when creating `A` on the free store?  Implying shared should be a default is a bad idea.

Comment: @Yakk yes, of course, you are encourage to edit the post yourself next time, this is StackOverflow, we care about the best possible answers, not the person who wrote it.

Answer (score 5):

You're confusing two things:

- memory being released
- the destructor being called

You've shown that the latter doesn't occur, which makes sense: how can you destroy something that wasn't properly constructed? Note that the member variables *will* have their destructors invoked, though, because by the time the constructor threw an exception all the member variables had been fully constructed.

But that has nothing to do with memory being released, which *will* assuredly occur.

> `[C++11: 15.2/2]:` An object of any storage duration whose initialization or destruction is terminated by an exception will have destructors executed for all of its fully constructed subobjects (excluding the variant members of a union-like class), that is, for subobjects for which the principal constructor (12.6.2) has completed execution and the destructor has not yet begun execution. Similarly, if the non-delegating constructor for an object has completed execution and a delegating constructor for that object exits with an exception, the object’s destructor will be invoked. If the object was allocated in a new-expression, the matching deallocation function (3.7.4.2, 5.3.4, 12.5), if any, is called to free the storage occupied by the object.